# DocumentExtractionSkill not actually extracting document ; still showing base 64 text

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have the following indexer, and skillset. However, as shown in the output below, the document extraction is not working as expected even using Microsoft own example

Skillset

```json
    {
 "@odata.context": "https://<resource>.search.windows.net/$metadata#skillsets/$entity",
 "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DBF5E21D1A188B\"",
 "name": "document-extraction-skill",
 "description": "",
 "skills": [
   {
     "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.DocumentExtractionSkill",
     "name": "#1",
     "description": null,
     "context": "/document",
     "parsingMode": "default",
     "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata",
     "inputs": [
       {
         "name": "file_data",
         "source": "/document/file_data"
       }
     ],
     "outputs": [
       {
         "name": "content",
         "targetName": "extracted_content"
       },
       {
         "name": "normalized_images",
         "targetName": "extracted_normalized_images"
       }
     ],
     "configuration": {
       "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages",
       "normalizedImageMaxWidth@odata.type": "#Int64",
       "normalizedImageMaxWidth": 2000,
       "normalizedImageMaxHeight@odata.type": "#Int64",
       "normalizedImageMaxHeight": 2000
     }
   },
   {
     "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Util.ShaperSkill",
     "name": "#3",
     "description": null,
     "context": "/document",
     "inputs": [
       {
         "name": "content",
         "source": "/document/extracted_content"
       },
       {
         "name": "normalized_images",
         "source": "/document/extracted_normalized_images"
       }
     ],
     "outputs": [
       {
         "name": "output",
         "targetName": "object_projection"
       }
     ]
   }
 ],
 "cognitiveServices": {
   "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.DefaultCognitiveServices",
   "description": null
 },
 "knowledgeStore": {
   "storageConnectionString": "<connectionstring>",
   "identity": null,
   "projections": [
     {
       "tables": [],
       "objects": [
         {
           "storageContainer": "search-experiment-data-container",
           "referenceKeyName": null,
           "generatedKeyName": "key",
           "source": "/document/object_projection",
           "sourceContext": null,
           "inputs": []
         }
       ],
       "files": []
     }
   ],
   "parameters": {
     "synthesizeGeneratedKeyName": true
   }
 },
 "indexProjections": null,
 "encryptionKey": null
}
```

Indexer

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://<resource>.search.windows.net/$metadata#indexers/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "\"0x8DBF5E2A0476504\"",
  "name": "scanned-pdf-indexer",
  "description": null,
  "dataSourceName": "scanned-pdf-source",
  "skillsetName": "document-extraction-skill",
  "targetIndexName": "dummy-index-knowledge-store",
  "disabled": null,
  "schedule": null,
  "parameters": {
    "batchSize": null,
    "maxFailedItems": null,
    "maxFailedItemsPerBatch": null,
    "base64EncodeKeys": null,
    "configuration": {
      "indexedFileNameExtensions": ".json",
      "allowSkillsetToReadFileData": true,
      "imageAction": "generateNormalizedImages"
    }
  },
  "fieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "metadata_storage_name",
      "targetFieldName": "id",
      "mappingFunction": {
        "name": "base64Encode",
        "parameters": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputFieldMappings": [
    {
      "sourceFieldName": "/document/extracted_content",
      "targetFieldName": "content"
    }
  ],
  "cache": null,
  "encryptionKey": null
}
```

Input

```json
{
  "values": [
    {
      "recordId": "1",
      "data":
      {
        "file_data": {
          "$type": "file",
          "data": "aGVsbG8="
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

output ( which is wrong, the data should have been bare text 'hello' but still it is base 64. What went wrong

```json
{"content":"{\r\n  \"values\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"recordId\": \"1\",\r\n      \"data\":\r\n      {\r\n        \"file_data\": {\r\n          \"$type\": \"file\",\r\n          \"data\": \"aGVsbG8=\"\r\n        }\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}\n","normalized_images":[]}
```

Comment: Where did you put the input? The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-document-extraction) shows the payload that goes into the skill, but that's not what the content of the document should necessarily be. The skillset definition is setup so it expects the document to contain a root property named "file_data" that contains the MIME64-encoded file contents. That data has to be set there somehow. That can be the output of another skill, or it can be from the document fetched from the data source.

Comment: The data source is in the blob as a json. I copied and pasted it in json blob file. Also the documentations says
The file reference object can be generated one of three ways:

Setting the allowSkillsetToReadFileData parameter on your indexer definition to "true". This creates a path /document/file_data that is an object representing the original file data downloaded from your blob data source. This parameter only applies to files in Blob storage.

I did also try just { '$type': 'file', data="base64"}, it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the output of `allowSkillsetToReadFileData` to the DocumentExtractionSkill. I'm assuming that the JSON document in blob storage looks something like this:

```
{
  "file_data": {
    "$type": "file",
    "data": "aGVsbG8="
  }
}
```

What is happening then is that the `/document/file_data` reference that is generated from `allowSkillsetToReadFileData` is actually the binary that represents a document that contains the above text. It makes sense then that the extraction that is happening is extracting the text from the document exactly as it is, and not detecting the separate file reference stored within it.

If you instead want to able to parse a reference to a different file within a JSON in blob storage, then you would need to pull out that specific key from within the JSON using `parsingMode` : `json`, and then reference it by the key name as input to the DocumentExtractionSkill. So your new `indexer.parameters.configuration` would look like this:

```
"configuration": {
    "indexedFileNameExtensions": ".json",
    "parsingMode": "json"
}
```

And then assuming that the key within your JSON is `file_data` everything else should just work.

Comment: Following up on this, the above should work, but it currently doesn't. I will see about getting this support added.

Comment: I have tried every possible combination and didn't work

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, it looks like we'll have to push a fix for this, which will take some time. I'll keep you posted. In the meantime, maybe we can try to find a workaround that would work for your scenario. Can you give a little more details about what you''re looking to achieve?

Comment: My team is working to build a search for our internal documents and we need this extraction feature, since we have documents, images  etc. We were evaluating this skill if it would work for us or not

Comment: @CareyHalton Got another issue as well on a different skill: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77748003/how-is-the-azure-search-custom-entity-lookup-cognitive-skill-external-file-stru/77748614#77748614