# How is the Azure Search: Custom Entity Lookup cognitive skill external file structured?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-ai

The Azure Search functionalities seem to be just half-baked. My team is working on to have a search service for our big internal data and I am experimenting with Azure search. One of the things I am experimenting is Custom Entity Lookup skill. As far as the inline definition, it works fine. However, since I have custom entity definition more than 10kb, I want to define my custom entities in external file and I did define one and put it in the azure blob, and set the URL from the blob file to entitiesDefinitionUri of the skill . However, I get the following error when I run the indexer
"
Failed to parse Custom Entity Definition file at https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/search-experiment-data-container/guideline/terms.json as json."

I define my file as

```json
[
   {
    "id": "someId",
    "name": "Some defintion",
    "description": "Some description",
    "fuzzyEditDistance": 3,
    "defaultCaseSensitive": false

   }
]
```

Has anyone got this working?

[UPDATE]

It looks a bug from Azure Search. There are two scenarios

1. parsingMode cannot be set to json and use the Custom entity skill extraction

There is an implementation conflict between reading a data source and reading custom entity definition in the indexer.

The "default" parsing mode is used for a variety of data formats, not just JSON. When you switch to this mode, the indexer may interpret the structure of the data source differently, which can cause issues if the data source is specifically formatted for JSON.

Data Sources and Custom Entity definitions should have been treated differently as they are completely used in different contexts. My data source for the indexer is a JSON and should be parsed as a JSON for I am **mapping** fields directly to my index. My Custom Entity definition is a  JSON not cvs, but MS doc recommends to use **default** parsingMode for such when using Custom Entity lookup skills , which screws up everything because you cannot use default parsing mode for a json data source that you map to indexer

The parsing mode setting in an indexer applies to how the indexer processes the data source. The recommendation to use the "default" parsing mode for custom entity definitions in a skillset does screw up the requirement for a "json" parsing mode for JSON data sources.

2. parsingMode set to default and use custom entity skill.
   I use a ShaperSkill to parse the JSON properties that I map to the index as workaround ( including the workaround I did in 3 below). I put my custom entity definition in blob storage and use sas token url  ( tested it with browser and verified url works). I set the parsing mode default. But still getting the error

Failed to parse Custom Entity Definition file at https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/search-experiment-data-container/guideline/terms.json as json."

But when I put the custom entity definition file in github and the raw file link, indexer execution worked.  However, this will not work for my use case; our data should be kept private, and the Custom entity skill does not mention any kind of auth to get the custom entity definition.

3. index key if not mapped in the fieldMappings eventhough defined/mapped in outputFieldmappings of the indexer, it errors.

I used default parsingMode and move all fieldmappings to outputFieldMappings, and use ShaperSkill to read properties of a json (workaround) and the key of index is mapped within the outputFieldMappings using the outputs of the ShaperSkill but this results in the error. "This ADLS Gen2 indexer maps the property 'metadata_storage_path' to
the index key, which may not reindex documents if directories are
renamed. Update the 'LastModified' timestamps for all the blobs in
the directory to ensure they get reindexed."

so my conclusion for this third scenario is that the key has to be mapped within fieldMappings of the indexer otherwise defaults to metadata_storage_path.

so still my original problem is not solved. Plus, We don't want put our custom definition publicly, there should have been auth/autho baked into the Custom Entity Lookup skill

Comment: Can you try `caseSensitive` instead of `defaultCaseSensitive`? This may be a documentation bug as the latter property is read-only on the entity definitions and should not be shown there.

Comment: I wasn't able to repro the error with the above entity json format. Would you be able to open a support case and provide a sample entity file for further debugging?

Comment: @Sophiac  I tried to put the file in github and used the raw file url. it worked with parseMode default but I had to migrate fieldMappings to the outputfieldmappings, after reading the json property using ShaperSkill,  and I had to do other workarounds as well but with sas token url from blob it does error consistently

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the updates. We found some additional information that I'll summarize here.

When you attempted to read with auth from blob storage, there was an error, likely in authentication, that erroneously translated as a parsing error. We're fixing that bug, so when that happens in the future, the error message will be less confusing. Pointing the indexer to a publicly accessible file works fine because you're not hitting that same auth error.

To work around the issue, you can try to get logs from the blob storage side to narrow down what the error was exactly. We've verified on our side that using blob storage with a SAS token does work.

We can more directly assist you in getting this to work through a support ticket.

Finally, parsing mode seems to be a red herring: the data source parsing mode has no effect on whether the entity definition file gets read as JSON or CSV. We attempt to parse as JSON, and if that fails and the file doesn't have a ".json" extension, we try CSV. In your case, since the file does have that extension, we don't even try CSV.

Comment: I think auth is not an issue. I can see the json data by even browsing it in a browser using the sas token url. In addition, I can do a simple GET on postman and still see the data without any additional auth just using sas token url. Not sure what causes the issue

Comment: SO apparently ate my last comment, so I'll restate it. My answer was based on analysis of your logs and of the codepath corresponding to that error. Auth is just one of the possible causes, it may be any number of other issues in the communication between the search service and the blob service. That's why I was advising to take a look at the logs on the blob storage side.